# When Selecting Vertice in Scripting, it isn't registered as active

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to select all Vertices along a specific edge

```
obj.data.vertices[x].select = True
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT') 
bpy.ops.mesh.select_axis()
```

Whenever `bpy.ops.mesh.select_axis()`is triggered it tells me

```
Warning: This operator requires an active vertex (last selected)
{'CANCELLED'}
```

Even though they come up in the editor as selected.

It needs to be done programmatically but selecting a Vertex in blender then doing `bpy.ops.mesh.select_axis()` does exactly what i need it to do.

Any ideas? I appreciate the help :)

Comment: Selected and active are not the same thing.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Ended up fixing it, Just always assumed an Active Vertex was the last Selected one automatically